# Taking url value and using it to from another search

Tags: php, url, search

I want to take a value from the url "query" and post it into this search box.

```
<input name="query" type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" value="<?php  $_POST["query"] ; ?>" />
```

I have a Search engine and it offers alternative search results, these a presented as links and once clicked the value is assigned to the end of the url like this:  `"Wedn.php?query=spicery"`

How can I get this value and input it into the search engine?

Comment: <input name="query" type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" value="<?php  $_POST["query"] ; ?>" /><br />

Comment: For one thing, you're missing `echo` in `<?php  $_POST["query"] ; ?>` Try `<?php  echo $_POST['query']; ?>`

Comment: In a nutshell, you need to use your `$query` variable, and echo it inside your field, i.e. `<input type="text" name="query" size="24" value="<?php echo $_POST['query'] ; ?>">` and implement it somehow in your code. You may need to use `GET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget echo befor $_POST["query"].
use this code:

```
<?php echo $_GET["query"]; ?>
```

Comment: I changed it to <?php echo $_POST["query"]; ?> but still does not seem to be populating the search box...

Comment: change all $_POST['query'] to $_GET['query'].

Comment: Thanks but that broke the program the normal searches were not longer being carried out...

Comment: why?what is the problem?

Comment: Well if I make them GET it stops working the query is not being posted so that a step backwards really.

Comment: you just change $_POST['query'] to $_GET['query'] and not chnage all GET to POST.

Comment: you try "Wedn.php?query=love" this code worked.I tested this code in localhost. http://i.cubeupload.com/qmAFE7.jpg

Comment: Use this code. http://codepad.org/akrJUvdT .If this code help you please click checkbox on the left answer.

Comment: I use your code -- the search does not activate with it so no suggestions are offered.